# Why should I typecast a 32 bit address to 16 bit to store a 16 bit data

Tags: c, casting, stm32, flash-memory

I am working on an STM32 Flash, I came across this function that writes 16-bit data to an address that is 32-bit. Why should I typecast this address like `*(__IO uint16_t*)Address = Data;` which expands to `*(volatile uint16_t *)Address = Data;`

```
static void FLASH_Program_HalfWord(uint32_t Address, uint16_t Data)
{
  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_FLASH_ADDRESS(Address));
  
  /* If the previous operation is completed, proceed to program the new data */
  CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_PSIZE);
  FLASH->CR |= FLASH_PSIZE_HALF_WORD;
  FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_PG;

  *(__IO uint16_t*)Address = Data;
}
```

I expect `*((uint32_t *)Address) = data` to be sufficient.

Comment: The size of an address is always, potentially, different from the size of the data object stored at that address.

Comment: `Address` is just a number. The cast `(__IO uint16_t *)` converts the number into a pointer. Then dereferencing the pointer with `*` allows you to access the memory at that address.

Comment: You can't use unary `*` on an integer (a plain number).  You need a pointer.

Comment: @ Steve Summit ,  `*((uint32_t *)Address) = data`  vs `*((uint16_t *)Address) = data`, in the former case we are wasting 2 bytes as it will be filled with 0, as each memory location is of 1 byte. Am I correct ?

Comment: @SteveSummit flash controller needs to know how many bits to burn.

Comment: @PaulsonRajaL If `FLASH_Program_HalfWord` is intended to write two bytes / 16 bits, then saying `*((uint32_t *)Address) = data` would be very wrong.  It's not that it would "waste" two bytes, but rather, it would likely overwrite two extra bytes it's not supposed to.

Comment: @0___________ sorry... get carried away. Usually writing 4 bytes instead of 2 is a problem, but since I don't know a thing about FLASH programming (really) I should not have assumed if it may have similar problems compared to regular code. Comments deleted as wrong - this one will be gone too (or flag as NLN).

Comment: There's no way to answer without reading the friendly manual apart the specific flash. Which in turn requires the exact STM32 part number. There's some flash types like emulated eeprom where you can only write certain sizes - erase/word size/alignment of the flash memory itself does not necessarily correspond with the CPU.

Comment: The `volatile` is also important: It tells the compiler that the address you are writing either does not behave like RAM or (if it is RAM) it is accessed from outside the regular program flow (interrupts, DMA ...). If you write to RAM, it does not care if you do this before or after writing `FLASH->CR`. So the compiler may optimize the program and write to `Address` before writing to `FLASH->CR` if the `volatile` is not there.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer is a memory address. A memory address itself is 32-bit. It is the data it's pointing to that is different. When you have pointer to 32-bit integer, the compiler generates instructions that load and store 32 bits of data at a time. When you have a pointer to 16-bit integer, the compiler generates instructions that load and store 16 bits of data. Imagine example:

```
MemAdd: 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103
MemVal: 0xFF  0xFF  0xFF  0xFF
```

Pointer: 0x100

if you `*(uint32_t*)(Pointer) = 0x1234`, the memory at 0x100-0x103 will contain `0x00001234`. If you `*(uint16_t*)(Pointer) = 0x1234`, the memory at 0x100-0x103 will contain `0xFFFF1234`. The other two bytes were never overwritten.

Since you want to write half-word to flash, you want to tell the compiler to generate instructions for storing 16-bit value.

Answer (score 1):

This operation converts it to the **pointer to `uint16_t`** and then dereferences it. It is done to **force** use of 16 bits write/read instructions in the generated code.

```
void write16(uint32_t addr, uint16_t val)
{
    *(volatile uint16_t *)addr = val;
}

void write8(uint32_t addr, uint16_t val)
{
    *(volatile uint8_t *)addr = val;
}


void write32(uint32_t addr, uint16_t val)
{
    *(volatile uint32_t *)addr = val;
}
```

```
write16:
        strh    r1, [r0]        @ movhi
        bx      lr
write8:
        uxtb    r1, r1
        strb    r1, [r0]
        bx      lr
write32:
        str     r1, [r0]
        bx      lr
```

When programing flash it is very important as it is not "normal" write to the memory.

Comment: @0___________The write8 function would just write the first nibble or last nibble of the `val` to the address.

Comment: @PaulsonRajaL you did not understand the example. It shows the instructions generated to guarantee the correct bus access size.

Comment: It's important to use a write of the correct size even when not writing flash. No idea what you think writing to flash is special here. // And PRL is right. `write8` probably should have a `uint8_t` argument.

Comment: @PaulsonRajaL Why would `write8` write a nybble, which is `4`bits? What do you mean? I've never seen a CPU that can read/write 4-bits from memory.

Comment: @ikegami argument size does not matter. I have shown that it will generate `strb` instruction.

Comment: I think argument sizes in your example make this confusing. For example, why is `val` type `uint16_t` in `write32`?